# I want to parse a Terraform vars file and store variables from the TF vars file as vars in a Makefile

Tags: awk, make

I have two files: a Terraform variables file (`vars.tf`), and a Makefile.

What I want to be able to do, is to have the Makefile "read" some of the variables in the Terraform `vars.tf` file.

The `vars.tf` file:

```
variable "region" {
    default = "us-west-1"
    description = "AWS Region"
}
variable "profile" {
    default = "bobs-profile"
    description = "Please enter your AWS CLI profile name"
}
variable "env" {
    default = "dev"
    description = "Please label the environment this infrastructure will be deployed to eg dev, uat, prod"
}
```

I would like to be able to call the variables listed in the `vars.tf` file in my Makefile - here is a short example:

```
.ONESHELL:
.SHELL := /usr/bin/bash
.PHONY: apply plan prep
VARS="variables/$(ENV)-$(REGION).tfvars"
CURRENT_FOLDER=$(shell basename "$$(pwd)")
AWS_PROFILE"bobs-profile"
```

I would like, for example, the values of:

- `$(ENV)`
- `$(REGION)`
- `$(AWS_PROFILE)`

To be pulled from the Terraform `vars.tf` file, so that the Makefile will be run with the variables as follows:

```
ENV=dev
REGION=us-west-1
AWS_PROFILE=bobs-profile
```

Is there a way that I can achieve this?

Comment: Did you consider using [tfvars.json](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#variable-definitions-tfvars-files) files and then processing them using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/)?

Answer (score 2):

The file that you show is written in HCL (the HashiCorp configuration language). It can be transformed to JSON, which makes it easier to parse with common tools like `jq`.

To convert your HCL file to JSON, you may use a tool such as `yj` (from https://github.com/sclevine/yj).  You may then have `jq` create the `make` command for you:

```bash
eval "$(
    yj -cj <vars.tf |
    jq -r '
        [
            "make",
            (.variable[] | keys[]) as $key |
                "\($key)=\(.variable[][$key][].default)"
        ] | @sh'
)"
```

For the given example, this creates the command

```bash
'make' 'env=dev' 'profile=bobs-profile' 'region=us-west-1'
```

Which, when evaluated, would run the `make` with the named variables set to the mentioned values.  The variables would be in lower case, which is what you want.  Note, for example, that setting `ENV` may influence the way shell commands in a Makefile are executed (`ENV` is a special variable in the shell, which may point to a file that the shell should source upon startup).

You could also get the variables and values as a tab-delimited list that you then read in the shell:

```bash
set --

yj -cj <vars.tf |
jq -r '
    (.variable[] | keys[]) as $key |
    [ $key, .variable[][$key][].default ] |
    @tsv' |
{
    while IFS=$'\t' read -r key value; do
        set -- "$@" "$key"="$value"
    done

    make "$@"
}
```

This would collect the variables and their values in the list of positional parameters, and then invoke `make` with them.  The command that would executed, given the document in the question, would be the equivalent of

```bash
make 'env=dev' 'profile=bobs-profile' 'region=us-west-1'
```

---

For reference, the JSON document created by `yj` above, would be the equivalent of the following:

```json
{
  "variable": [
    {
      "region": [
        {
          "default": "us-west-1",
          "description": "AWS Region"
        }
      ],
      "profile": [
        {
          "default": "bobs-profile",
          "description": "Please enter your AWS CLI profile name"
        }
      ],
      "env": [
        {
          "default": "dev",
          "description": "Please label the environment this infrastructure will be deployed to eg dev, uat, prod"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have GNU `make`, you can use the `shell` command to assign the result of an external command to a Makefile variable.

For your case, you could use:

```
ENV:=$(shell awk '$$1=="variable" && $$2=="\"env\"" {i=1} $$1=="}" {i=0} i && $$1=="default" {split($$0,a,"\""); print a[2]}' test.tf)

REGION:=$(shell awk '$$1=="variable" && $$2=="\"region\"" {i=1} $$1=="}" {i=0} i && $$1=="default" {split($$0,a,"\""); print a[2]}' test.tf)

AWS_PROFILE:=$(shell awk '$$1=="variable" && $$2=="\"profile\"" {i=1} $$1=="}" {i=0} i && $$1=="default" {split($$0,a,"\""); print a[2]}' test.tf)
```

This will look for regions of interest starting with `variable` and ending with `}`, set a flag `i` when the "correct" region was found, and if that flag is set and a line with keyword `default` encountered, it will extract the element in double-quotes (`" ... "`).

Note that double `$$` are necessary since `make` will interpret the entire content of `$( ... )` (without respect to the `' ... '`), and to pass a literal `$` to the `shell` command we need to "escape" it by prepending another `$`.

It is a little clumsy (a loop construct would be nicer since the parsing structure is basically the same for all three) but it should work.